# Using a variable for milliseconds in setTimeout (javascript)

Tags: javascript, settimeout, parseint

I am using a text area to display the time, an input field to get a number and a button to execute the function:

```html
<textarea name="demo" id="demo"></textarea><br> 
<input type="number" id="seconds" name="seconds"></p><br> 
<button type="button" name="refresh" onclick="refresh()">Refresh after number of seconds.</button>
```

For the javascript portion, I am taking the value of the input and storing it in a millisecond variable:

```js
// store input as a variable:
var seconds = document.getElementById("seconds").value;
// convert input to a number
var milliseconds = parseInt(seconds, 10);
// convert number to milliseconds
milliseconds *= 1000;
```

But when I use this millisecond variable in the setTimeout function, it doesn't work:

```js
function refresh() {
  var refreshTime = setTimeout(displayTime, milliseconds);
}

function displayTime() {
  var timeNow = new Date();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = timeNow.toLocaleTimeString();
}
```

If I manually add a number to the setTimeout function, it will work, so I'm thinking I did something wrong in creating the millisecond variable.  Could someone help me where I went wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: maybe it's because you should read the textbox value when you press the button... not once for all on top of the scope. I would put the fetch statement inside the refresh function

Comment: Please combine your code into one runnable snippet.

Comment: It's very difficult to see the actual problem with your code broken into three snippets, but for what it's worth, all you have to do is copy the contents of the second snippet into the start of the `refresh()` function and it will work as expected.

Comment: newbie to stackoverflow!  don't know how to do snippets yet, but I'll make sure to fix it for next time (....... and I'm sure there will be many next times!)  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where you went wrong:-
You are getting the value of the input at the very beginning, when the user has not inputted any value. Thus `setTimeout` receives a [`NaN`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number_nan.asp#:%7E:text=In%20JavaScript%2C%20NaN%20is%20short,the%20same%20as%20the%20Number.) (because you are trying to parse an empty string) as its argument.

You can fix that very easily, by getting the value of the text box every time the refresh button is clicked.

So the final result would look like this:-

```js
function refresh() {
  // store input as a variable:
  var seconds = document.getElementById("seconds").value;
  // convert input to a number
  var milliseconds = parseInt(seconds); // You dont need to pass in a second argument because by default radix is 10.
  // convert number to milliseconds
  milliseconds *= 1000;

  var refreshTime = setTimeout(displayTime, milliseconds);
}

function displayTime() {
  var timeNow = new Date();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = timeNow.toLocaleTimeString();
}
```

```html
<textarea name="demo" id="demo"></textarea><br>
<!-- I have added a min attribute to restrict it from being negative -->
<input type="number" min="0" id="seconds" name="seconds"></p><br>
<button type="button" name="refresh" onclick="refresh()">Refresh after number of seconds.</button>
```

Comment: That's it!!  Thank you so much, it works now!  Sorry for 3 different snippets, new to stackoverflow and don't know the etiquette :)

Comment: Hi @mag. If this has solved your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Thank you :)